# Handle button press state

Tags: android, statelistdrawable

I have a button in android application that has an accompanying red-circle `TextView` that represents a counter (iOS-style):

[image]

Button is a `StateListDrawable` so that when pressed is (visually) goes slightly down. I want accompanying red circle to go down as well.

I would be happy if I could found a callback that tells me when the button goes to pressed or unpressed (normal) state. I tried `btn.setOnTouchListener`, but it does not work. For instance, when I press button, it fires `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and that's good. But if I drag my finger out of button, it jumps back to normal state, but MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is not fired until I release my finger.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do this

1. Include `Button` and `TextView` in one layout and set click listener to that layout.
2. Perform `TextView` click inside `Button` click listener. see below code.

   ```
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           textView.performClick();    
      }
   });
   ```